# How do I store multiple user changes locally with efficient Javascript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, javascript-objects, contenteditable

On my static webpage, users should be able to edit multiple texts and store changes locally to continue editing later. I put this together from code snippets by others (I myself am not a very competent user of Javascript).

https://jsfiddle.net/x2thdrw3/54/

```js
window.onload = function() {

  if (localStorage.getItem('userContent01')) {
    document.querySelector('#userContent01').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('userContent01');
  }

  if (localStorage.getItem('userContent02')) {
    document.querySelector('#userContent02').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('userContent02');
  }


}

let editBtn01 = document.querySelector('#userContent01_edit');
let content01 = document.querySelector('#userContent01');

editBtn01.addEventListener('click', () => {
  localStorage.setItem('userContent01', content01.innerHTML);
});

let editBtn02 = document.querySelector('#userContent02_edit');
let content02 = document.querySelector('#userContent02');

editBtn02.addEventListener('click', () => {
  localStorage.setItem('userContent02', content02.innerHTML);
});
```

```css
.userContent {
  border: ridge 2px;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 2em;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="userContent" , id="userContent01" contenteditable="true">
  Edit this first text and then click save to store your changes for later.
</div>

<button id="userContent01_edit">Store changes to the first text locally</button>


<div class="userContent" , id="userContent02" contenteditable="true">
  Edit this second text and then click save to store your changes for later.
</div>

<button id="userContent02_edit">Store changes to the second text locally</button>

<br>
<br>

<input type="button" value="Reload and keep local storage" onClick="location.reload()">

<input type="button" value="Reload and clear local storage" onClick="localStorage.clear() + location.reload()">
```

The example is not efficient because the Javascript code would grow with each additional text.

What would be a more efficient way to have multiple of these editable and storable divs on my webpage?

On the webpage, the divs do not occur one after the other, like in the example, but with other noneditable content in between.

<s>P.S.: The code works on jsfiddle but stackoverflow throws a security error. I do not understand why.</s> (Clarified by J. Titus in the comments.)

P.P.S.: I am aware that I am asking a rather specific question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Use <ul> <li></li><ul> type relationship and use the parent (<ul>) to get all the children (<li>) and loop through them and assign listeners , set innerTexts etc..

Comment: StackOverflow throws a security error because the code attempts to read and write values from the browser's localStorage.

Comment: @JohnYepthomi Thank you for your reply. The editable texts do not occur one after the other in the form of a list but with all kinds of noneditable content in between.

Comment: @J.Titus Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A very compact implementation.** (*Looks lengthy because of all the comments.*)

```
window.onload = function () {
  //Get all userContent elements
  let userContent_els = document.querySelectorAll(".user-content");
  
  //Loop over each userContent element
  userContent_els.forEach((el) => {
    // easy access using the id of the user content as key
    let key = el.id;
    let value = localStorage.getItem(key);

    if(value)
      el.innerText = value;
  });
};

//Get all button elements
let editButton_els = document.querySelectorAll(".edit-button");

//Loop over each button
editButton_els.forEach((button) => {
  let buttonId = button.id;

  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    /* Storage key is a combination of 'content-' and the button 'id'.
       This combination is intentional as to make it easier getting the data later as we 
       just have to get the content 'id' which is set to 'content-01', 'content-02' etc..*/

    // Get corresponding userContent element
    let content_el = document.querySelector(`#content-${buttonId}`);

    localStorage.setItem(
     "content-" + buttonId,
     content_el.innerText
    );
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="user-content" , id="content-01" contenteditable="true">
  Edit this first text and then click save to store your changes for later.
</div>

<button class="edit-button" id="01">Store changes to the first text locally</button>

<div class="user-content" , id="content-02" contenteditable="true">
  Edit this second text and then click save to store your changes for later.
</div>

<button class="edit-button" id="02">Store changes to the second text locally</button>

<br>
<br>

<input type="button" value="Reload and keep local storage" onClick="location.reload()">

<input type="button" value="Reload and clear local storage" onClick="localStorage.clear() + location.reload()">
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! For some reason, the predefined content of the div ("Edit this first text and then click save to store your changes for later.") is not displayed but that's only a minor concern.

Comment: That’s because on window.onLoad changes the content to previously saved values from localStorage. And if nothing was set in previous load then value will be null and hence, will set a null value to userContent element. What you can do is check if storage value is null to ignore setting it.

Comment: @DanielJach please check my updated answer. Changes made in the window.onLoad() function

Comment: It worked, thank you again. If you don't mind, could you quickly elaborate what this bit does? The other parts of your code are transparent to me (though I would not have been able to write them myself) but this bit confuses me. Should it not be if(!value) to check wether storage value is null?

Comment: in javascript, if a value is null or undefined it will be falsy , so the if check will fail if it’s either null or undefined. But I’m with you on the fact that it’s not very informative and it’s better to do an explicit check for readability. So, I would recommend doing explicit checks as well.

Comment: @DanielJach I would recommend reading this from MDN beyond null and undefined[Javascript truthy explained](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy#:~:text=In%20JavaScript%2C%20a%20truthy%20value,type%20coercion%20in%20Boolean%20contexts.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you could do this. One option is to loop through each div with "contenteditable" and apply the logic

```
window.onload = () =>
    document.querySelectorAll('[contenteditable="true"]').forEach((element) => {
      const elementId = element.getAttribute("id");

      if (localStorage.getItem(elementId)) {
        element.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem(elementId);
      }

      document
        .getElementById(`${elementId}_edit`)
        .addEventListener("click", () => {
          localStorage.setItem(elementId, element.innerHTML);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got this to work once I changed "data-content-editable" back to "contenteditable". But I would still need to add onload functions for each div I have stored.

Comment: Apologies yes, I hadn't ever seen the "contenteditable" attribute and assumed it was a custom one. I've updated my answer to use the HTML you provided.

Comment: There really is no reason to apologize. Thank you for your revision. This solution works, too. I have upvoted it.